# How to use normal string to match a regexp string with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I stored a document in elasticsearch, one of whose fields is a regexp expression, then I hope to use a normal string to hit the document, is it possible?
For example, in elasticsearch, there is one document like :

```
{
    "service_id": "service1",
    "regexp_url": "abc.*"
}
```

then I hope to use the string "abcde" to hit the document, is it possible?

The detail user case is: 
I have a website and each page is corresponding to a service, also different pages can also corresponded to the same service. 
Now I have an es index, it contains two fields: service_id, regexp_url (it means the page's url matched the url regexp will be mapped to the service), now I open a page with url: "abcde", and the document is like above, I want to hit the document to find the serviceId.

Comment: I'm curious about your use case, do you mind explaining it in more details?

Answer (score -1):

```
 POST <INDEX>/_search
 {
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
  "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
      "regexp": {
        "<YOUR_FIELD>": {
          "value": "<YOUR_REGEX_PATTER"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
```

More Reference :https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

Comment: You are using a regexp to hit a document with a normal string value while I hope to use a normal string to hit a document with a regexp value....

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Please learn how to write regex patterns. then you can realize what I'm said. And here   I mention your pattern (regular expression value )  should be "john~athon<1-5>" , "aaa.+&.+bbb" .......

Comment: I see, I have made a mistake about es's regexp, I have changed the regexp to  "abc.*", and changed the url to "abcde", but it still cannot solve my problem...